# Fullcalendar doesn't display day/week hours properly

Tags: jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

Im using fullcalendar to make an advertising system that shows in your mobile phone an alert when you have an event at that time. 
I have made a web where you can put the events, and then the system saves them on a MySQL database. 
It works well, saving the start and end hours (and days), but, when I click on the day or week view and select a range of hours, after I put the name of the event, the selection goes to the allDay block. 
Then, if I refresh the web, it shows the event on the 0:00-2:00 space, no matter the size (in hours) you made before. 
Anyway, in the DB, its saved correctly, and the mobile alerts works well.
I suppose it's a wrong configuration of the 'defaults' display options, but I am unable to find it.

This is the code on the main page.

```
//Fullcalendar script
$(document).ready(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events: "events.php",

            // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
            eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                    event.allDay = true;
                } else {
                    event.allDay = false;
                }
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var title = prompt('Aviso:');
                //var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
                if (title) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format();
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'add_events.php',
                        data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(json) {
                            alert('Añadido Correctamente\n\nSi desactivas la opción de crear dialogos adicionales no podrás añadir, editar o borrar eventos en el futuro.');
                        }
                    });
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                           title: title,
                           start: start,
                           end: end,
                           allDay: allDay
                        },
                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },

            editable: true,
            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format();
                var end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'update_events.php',
                    data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(json) {
                        alert("Actualizado correctamente\n\nSi desactivas la opción de crear dialogos adicionales no podrás añadir, editar o borrar eventos en el futuro.");
                    }
                });
            },
            eventClick: function(event) {
                var decision = confirm("¿Seguro que queieres hacerlo?"); 
                if (decision) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "delete_event.php",
                        data: "&id=" + event.id,
                        success: function(json) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                            alert("Actualizado correctamente\n\nSi desactivas la opción de crear dialogos adicionales no podrás añadir, editar o borrar eventos en el futuro.");
                        }
                    });

                }
            },
            eventResize: function(event) {
                var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format();
                var end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'update_events.php',
                    data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(json) {
                        alert("Actualizado correctamente\n\nSi desactivas la opción de crear dialogos adicionales no podrás añadir, editar o borrar eventos en el futuro.");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I don't know if you would need any other of the files.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:
I have deleted the allDay: allDay here:

```
calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                       title: title,
                       start: start,
                       end: end,
                       allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
```

now, the event doesn't go to the allDay block space when I create it, but when I refresh the page, it shows still on the 0:00 to 2:00 space.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: Do you mean to give you the entire code?
It's a little.. confidential, so if it's that, Im not able to do it, even if I want to.

If you want some part of the fullcalendar code of course I can.
I hope anyone could figure what's going wrong.

Comment: Can you show the posted form data from when you create a problematic event. And the response data when fullcalendar fetches events after refreshing. You can get both of these on the network panel after pressing f12 on your browser.

Comment: After refresh Ive got a lot of scrips/docs uses, do you want one in specific?

Comment: yeah, the one that contains the events. It'll be called "events.php" or something.

Comment: I mean, your HTML structure and javascript/jquery code with your structure. I don't want your php code or something else. In your client side code there is no confidental side.

Comment: slicetoad, is this what you want? the only way I see to get that files was in '.har' format.
http://dropcanvas.com/naqsw

Comment: http://dropcanvas.com/naqsw
Here is a 'censured' version of the web. I think this way there is no problem to upload it :)
PD: I can post a download link, doesn't I?